# filebeat Grok for postgres log file not work

Tags: postgresql, filebeat, kibana-7

I am using filebeat in kibana to export and manage postgressql database log file .

version using is 7.13.3

Follow instruction at
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-postgresql.html

```
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] %q%u@%d '
log_duration = 'on'
log_statement = 'none'
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

Log was exported and put in kibana success but the Grok parsing meet the following error

> Provided Grok expressions do not match field value: [2021-07-20 16:07:24.606 +07,"postgres","hr",4988,"[local]",60f6920d.137c,3,"SELECT",2021-07-20 16:06:21 +07,9/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 445.927 ms  statement: select * from events_102078;",,,,,,,,,"psql"]

The raw log line in postgres_log.csv is

> 2021-07-20 16:07:24.606 +07,"postgres","hr",4988,"[local]",60f6920d.137c,3,"SELECT",2021-07-20 16:06:21 +07,9/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 445.927 ms  statement: select * from events_102078;",,,,,,,,,"psql"

So how can I fix this ?